# MongoDB aggregate or get the Mean daily average count of recorded documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb, math, mongoose-schema

I save the current time `Date.now()` every time I add a document to a MongoDB collection. Let's say these 3 documents with the following format:

```
# Doc 1
    {
      date: ISODate("2017-01-25T09:47:40.000Z"),
      reports: 5
    }
# Doc 2
    {
      date: ISODate("2017-01-24T09:47:40.000Z"),
      reports: 5
    }
# Doc 3
    {
      date: ISODate("2017-01-23T09:47:40.000Z"),
      reports: 5
    }
```

Basically, the math formula is `(total reports) divided by the (count of days from the oldest date until date today)`.

What would be the easiest/fastest way to do this aggregation using mongo shell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

`$match` to keep the records `$lte` than today, `$group` by `null` and calculate `$sum` to count the report, `$min`(oldest) date and `$project` to calculate the mean by dividing the total reports and count of days .

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        date: {
            $lt: new ISODate()
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        oldestDate: {
            $min: "$date"
        },
        sumReports: {
            $sum: "$reports"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        avgReports: {
            $divide: ["$sumReports", {
                $divide: [{
                    $subtract: [new ISODate(), "$oldestDate"]
                }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24]
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks man, really helpful! If I don't want to group them because I just want to get mean daily average of all the reports do I just have to remove everything in `_id`?

Comment: yeah change `_id:null`

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question to get the Mean daily average provided the math formula. Can you help me mongofy it? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Updated answer. Please take the latest when verifying.